# Парсинг страницы с подгружаемым контентом

Tags: javascript, парсер

нужна помощь!!! 
с помощью либы  request можно выцепить весь html с сайта, с этим все хорощо, если html сразу написан в документе, но вот если остальной контент формируется js, и появляется спустя некоторое время после загрузки самой страницы, то эта библиотека и представленный ниже код берут только тот html, который был сразу.
Подскажите как сделать задержку запроса или придется юзать другую либу ???

`let request = require('request');

let url = 'https://www.google.com/';

request(url, (err,res,body)=> {

```
    console.log(body);
```

});

`

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что как вы правильно заметили, на таких сайтах данные генерируются с помощью js, а request лишь выполняет http запрос. 
Единственный более-менее реальный способ сделать то, что вы хотите - это использовать так называемые headless chrome api, т.е. фактически открывать страницу в хром без отрисовки в ui. В случае nodejs например есть такой вариант https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

Selenuim webdriver позволяется дожидаться полной загрузки страницы. 
А webdriver, который вам нужен уже выберете сами.